# dataGridView form component and colored m*n table

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I'm trying to display the table of `m*n` cells with some text in each cell, and the background colors of each cell could be different.

Am I right the dataGridView component could be used exactly for this purpose?
If yes, then how to make the dataGridView to contain more then just one empty row? Let's say I want it 5*5 cells and the cells could be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values to a `DataGridView` control in many ways: from a database, from a `Collection` (`Array`, `DataTable`, etc.), directly row by row, etc. In each cell you can put the (string) values you want, including ""/empty. Here you have a sample code to get some inspiration:

```
int count = 0;
int maxCount = 5;
do
{
    count = count + 1;
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); //For adding empty rows, you can use this one
} while(count < maxCount);

dataGridView1[1, 2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1[3, 1].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
dataGridView1[4, 4].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

It takes `dataGridView1` (a `DataGridView` with 5 columns added via "Design View"), adds 5 rows to it and colors the background of various cells.